# What does the weapon icon mean in Total War Attila

Tags: attila-total-war

In Attila (and in fact most recent Total War) every unit has a "weapon", often displayed in the  unit's name.
You can also see it in the form of a little icon on the unit card.
For example, Axe infantry use Axes, Spearmen use spears (obviously).

Do these icons means something more than what is already displayed in the unit stats (like numerical values )? 
Do Swordsmen have any hidden bonuses over Spearmen, for example ? Or Axemen against infantry? Or Spearmen against cavalry  ?

I looked in the game wiki but I found nothing specific about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak specifically to Attila, but every previous version of Total War has included inherent bonuses specific weapons have over other types of troops. It is almost always the case that spear-men are the best counter to Calvary (There is actually a case in Rome Total War and Medieval 2 Total War that triggers your advisor to warn you if you order cavalry to charge spear-men with him saying 'That's a pretty good way to get your cavalry killed').

I'm currently looking for an official source, but from what I've found so far (in various forums) Axes are best against heavily armored infantry, Swords are best against Spear-men. As mentioned above spear-men are best against Cavalry. And Cavalry tend to be best against less armored or skirmish opponents.

Comment: I see you got what I meant. I didn't find any official material for this, I think I'll stick to the forum rumors.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned, the weapon icon indicates the type of unit.

I've found the following information relating to the strengths and weaknesses of the various types units in Atilla: Total War (and these should generally hold true for other Total War games as well). If I've missed any, feel free to edit or comment, and I'll try to add them.

### Infantry

**[Melee Infantry](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Melee_Infantry)**

Strengths: Average Missile Block Chance, Formations, Prolonged Combat

Weaknesses: Flanking, Persistent Missile Damage, Sea Sickness, Shock Cavalry

**[Spear Infantry](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Spear_Infantry)**

Strengths: Average Missile Block Chance, Disciplined, Fighting Cavalry, Formations, Good Armor, Strong vs. Charges

Weaknesses: Flanking, Persistent Missile Damage, Prolonged Combat (vs Melee Infantry), Sea Sickness

**[Pike Infantry](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Pike_Infantry)**

Strengths: Disciplined, Fighting Cavalry, Good Morale, Pike Wall, Strong vs Charges

Weaknesses: Flanking, Persistent Missile Damage, Prolonged Combat, Sea Sickness

**[Missile Infantry](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Missile_Infantry) (Archers)**

Strengths: Barrage, Flaming Shot, Heavy Shot, High Persistent Damage, Precision Shot, Whistling Shot

Weaknesses: Cavalry, Flanking, Poor Melee Attributes, Poor Morale, Prolonged Combat, Sea Sickness

### Cavalry

**[Melee Cavalry](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Melee_Cavalry)**

Strengths: Average Missile Block Chance, Diamond, Flanking, Good Charge, Good Morale, Strong Melee Attributes

Weaknesses: Aversion to Fire, Pike Infantry, Sharp Rock Beds, Shock Cavalry, Spear Infantry, Spike Traps, Suedes

[**Missile Cavalry**](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Missile_Cavalry)

Strengths: Barrage, Fire While Moving, Formations, Mobility, Precision Shot

Weaknesses: Aversion to Fire, Melee Cavalry, Persistent Missile Damage, Pike Infantry, Poor Missile Block Chance, Sea Sickness, Shock Cavalry, Spear Infantry

[**Shock Cavalry**](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Shock_Cavalry)

Strengths: Excellent Charge, Flanking, Good Armor, Good Health, Wedge

Weaknesses: Persistent Missile Damage, Pike Infantry, Prolonged Combat, Sea Sickness, Sharp Stone Beds, Spear Infantry, Spike Traps, Suedes

**[Elephants](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Elephant)**

Strengths: Fire While Moving, Flaming Shot, Heavy Shot, Powerful Charge, Scare (everyone), Whistling Shot

Weaknesses: Aversion to Fire, Run Amok, Sea Sickness

## Artillery

**[Field Artillery](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Field_Artillery)**

Strengths: Barrage, Excellent Missile Damage, Excellent Speed, Unit Penetration

Weaknesses: Cannot Run, Poor Melee, Poor Morale, Sea Sickness

**[Siege Artillery](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Siege_Artillery)**

Strengths: Barrage, Excellent Range, Explosive Shot, Flaming Shot, Siege Damage

Weaknesses: Melee Combat, Persistent Missile Damage, Poor Health, Poor Morale

### Ships

**[Artillery Ships](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Artillery_Ship)**

Strengths: Barrage, Douse Fire, Excellent Range, Flaming Shot, Good Hull Strength

Weaknesses: Flammable Vessel, Poor Boarding Actions, Poor Morale

**[Fire Ship](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Fire_Ship)**

Strengths: Douse Fire, Good Mobility, Greek Fire

Weaknesses: Flammable Vessel, Poor Boarding Actions, Poor Morale

**[Melee Ship](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Melee_Ship)**

Strengths: Douse Fire, Good Hull Strength, Good Morale, Strong Boarding Actions

Weaknesses: Flammable Vessel, Persistent Missile Damage, Prolonged Combat (while ashore)

**[Missile Ship](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Missile_Ship)**

Strengths: Douse Fire, Flaming Shot, Good Rate of Fire, Heavy Shot, Replenish Ammo, Whistling Shot

Weaknesses: Flammable Vessel, Poor Boarding Actions, Poor Hull Strength

**[Ramming Ship](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/total-war-attila/Ramming_Ship)**

Strengths: Devastating Ram, Douse Fire, Excellent Hull Strength, Ramming Speed!

Weaknesses: Flammable Vessel, Poor Boarding Actions, Poor Morale

Comment: All of the information about the unit types doesn't answer the question. The question is simply, what do the icons mean. That's all, the rest of this is not needed.

Comment: @n_palum I would disagree - the question asks about the bonuses; "Do Swordsmen have any hidden bonuses over Spearmen, for example ? Or Axemen against infantry? Or Spearmen against cavalry ?" I think that by providing this information, as well as confirming the purpose of the icons, that this answer is in fact complete

Comment: It's asking if the icon provides that information, does it indicate hidden bonuses etc - by answering what the icons represent you answer that

Comment: @n_palum While I see your side of it, I still think that providing the information, if nothing else, helps to provide a well-rounded answer. I think given the ambiguity of the question language the inclusion of the bonuses is appropriate

Comment: Your answer is well rounded and I thank you, but as @n_palum said I'm specifically looking about the weapon bonus/malus. For example, between an axe melee infantry and a sword melee infantry, is there difference tied to the weapon which is not indicated in the unit stat ?